# build.gradle error. Sorry couldnt put error here look in the body

Tags: java, gradle, discord

I am following a tutorial on the website "https://medium.com/discord-bots/making-a-basic-discord-bot-with-java-834949008c2b"I got the error **Receiver class com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.internal.DependencyFileCollection does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskDependency getBuildDependencies()' of interface org.gradle.api.Buildable.**

Here is my build.gradle code.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version'2.0.1'
}
mainClassName = "Main"

group 'BlueBot'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'net.dv8tion:JDA:4.0.0_62'
}
```

if you have anyway to fix this or have any other info you need let me know.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your shadow version

```
id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version'5.2.0'
```

You can find the latest versions on [GitHub](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/releases)